# Get most recent post from Facebook page, and display on website using new Graph API JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a website for a business. The business currently has a Facebook page. On the website i'm creating, i need to display the most recent Facebook post.

A Google search led me to a depreciated method, and Facebook says now to use the new Graph API, but i'm starting from no Facebook API experience so found it overwhelming and could use some help.

Here's where i am.

I'm doing this as a single page site with no server side language, so am only using JavaScript. So far I've got the FB JS SDK script after my body tag, and a app-id setup for my page.

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'your-app-id', // except real id
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.4'
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I have linked my FB app with my FB page. Now i need to display the most recent post on my website.

Comment: With API v2, you need an access token to request this kind of data. So if you want to do that client-side only, then you have to make users login with their FB account first. Server-side you could use your app access token or a page access token – but those must never be exposed in client-side code. Other than that, your only option would be to use the Page Plugin – that has an option to display the last X posts of the page.

Comment: Thanks, i guess the page plugin is the only way then, so this is technically the answer if you want to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}/feed",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed

You could just use the following API call to get only one entry:

```
/{page-id}/feed?limit=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I discovered this only works if i have users logging into the site which they are not. And like Cbroe said i have to use the Page Plugin unfortunately.

Comment: that is not correct, and not what CBroe said either. you can use an app access token, without any user login. you just have to use the app token server side.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'app id here',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v3.2'
        });
    
    //For getting posts from wall,
     FB.api(
      '/me',
      {access_token:'Access token here',
      fields:"id,name,posts{attachments}"},
      function(response) {
       console.log(response)
      }
     );
//for getting posts from page we manage
     FB.api(
        "/page_id/feed",
     {access_token:'access token',
     fields:"attachments{url,media,description,title,type},created_time,description,message,updated_time"},
        function (response) {
     console.log(response)
       if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */
          }
        }
    );
    };    
    (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: `access_token:'Access token here'` - nope, not in client-side code, that is a very big no-no.

Comment: Access token provided from fb developer account is big. I have given code to get both post from Wall and post from page we manage in fb.